# v0.19.0 composer network start failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Composer Version: 0.19.0

Mac OS

**Steps:**

- remove all images of docker
- rm -rf ~/.composer
- download the `fabric-tools` from network
- ./teardownFabric.sh
- ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
- ./startFabric.sh
- docker ps:

  > `CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
  >   504b51337d01        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0      "peer node start"        17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
  >   db82f914091d        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0   "orderer"                17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
  >   efcdff601fec        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
  >   fda7819674bd        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com`
- composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile basic-sample.bna (the bna file created before)
- composer network start --networkName basic-sample --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card

> Got error
>
> `✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (basic-sample:0.0.1))
>   Command failed`

**Retry:**

use npmrcFile:

- composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile basic-sample.bna -o npmrcFile=npmConfig.txt
- composer network start --networkName basic-sample --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card -o npmrcFile=npmConfig.txt

content of `npmConfig.txt`:

`registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org`

Still Failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the exact same problem as logged to an Issue on the Composer prpoject on GitHub.

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3794

The short answer to this is that the network name on the start command is wrong. The name of the network is likely to be basic-sample-network.

The way to check the Name and the Version is to issue this command:

`composer archive list -a basic-sample.bna`

Comment: please fix typo `s/prpoject/project/`